# SQL returning the count from wrong table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, left-join, ms-access-2010

This SQL is returning the record count of table Dims instead returning the record count of table BIDdetails. How can I fix?

```
BIDReportSearch.CommandText = ("SELECT BIDdetails.Origin, BIDdetails.Destination,
Round(Sum(Dims.ChargeableWeight)) as CWeight, count(BIDdetails.Origin) as NoOfShpt
FROM BIDdetails LEFT JOIN DIMS ON BidDetails.BID=Dims.BID
where BIDdetails.OrgCountry<>'AE' and BIDdetails.DestCountry='AE' and
BIDdetails.ClosingDate>=#" & dtpBIDfrom.Value & "# and BIDdetails.ClosingDate<=#" &
dtpBIDto.Value & "# GROUP BY BIDdetails.Origin, BIDdetails.Destination
ORDER BY Round(Sum(Dims.ChargeableWeight)) DESC")
```

Comment: Because, presumably, `Dims` has multiple rows for each row in `BIDetails`, although you haven't provided enough details for us to be sure.  You'd need to pre-aggregate in a subquery if that was the case.  Side note: concatenation is a great way to introduce SQL injection, you should be using paramterized queries.

Answer (score 1):

The expression:

```
count(BIDdetails.Origin)
```

simply counts the number of non-NULL values of `BIDdetails.Origin` in each group.  Because you are actually grouping by the field, that would be the number of rows in each group.

You can get what you want in most databases by using `count(distinct)` on a unique identifier.  Alas, MS Access doesn't support `count(distinct)` so such a query is much harder to write in Access.  You can get just the `count` field by doing:

```
SELECT BIDdetails.Origin, BIDdetails.Destination, count(*) as NoOfShpt
FROM BIDdetails 
where BIDdetails.OrgCountry <> 'AE' and BIDdetails.DestCountry='AE' and
      BIDdetails.ClosingDate>=#" & dtpBIDfrom.Value & "# and BIDdetails.ClosingDate<=#" & dtpBIDto.Value & "#
GROUP BY BIDdetails.Origin, BIDdetails.Destination;
```

And then combining the results either in your application or by joining this query back into the original one.

EDIT:

This is your original query:

```
SELECT d.Origin, d.Destination,
       Round(Sum(Dims.ChargeableWeight)) as CWeight, count(d.Origin) as NoOfShpt
FROM BIDdetails as d LEFT JOIN
     DIMS
     ON BidDetails.BID=Dims.BID
where d.OrgCountry <> 'AE' and d.DestCountry='AE' and
      d.ClosingDate> = #" & d.Value & "# and d.ClosingDate<=#" & dtpBIDto.Value & "#
GROUP BY d.Origin, d.Destination
ORDER BY Round(Sum(Dims.ChargeableWeight)) DESC
```

There is another approach, where you aggregate first by the details and then again.  I think that is easier in this case:

```
SELECT Origin, Destination, SUM(CWeight) as CWeight, COUNT(*) as NumShip
FROM (SELECT d.id, d.Origin, d.Destination,
             Round(Sum(Dims.ChargeableWeight)) as CWeight, count(d.Origin) as NoOfShpt
      FROM BIDdetails as d LEFT JOIN
           DIMS
           ON BidDetails.BID = Dims.BID
      where d.OrgCountry <> 'AE' and d.DestCountry='AE' and
            d.ClosingDate> = #" & d.Value & "# and d.ClosingDate<=#" & dtpBIDto.Value & "#
      GROUP BY d.id, d.Origin, d.Destination
     ) as d
GROUP BY Origin, Destination
ORDER BY Round(Sum(CWeight)) DESC;
```

`d.id` refers to whatever the unique id is for what you want to count.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your swift reply. Can you please give me the complete statement including **LEFT JOIN?** as the above is not working  for me.